# Changing the default simple_form datetime form in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime

I'm trying to modify the way simple_form allows users to input time in hours and minutes on a form.  My application is in Ruby on Rails (4) and it currently displays the year, month, and day well. However, the datetime (hours & minutes) is currently displayed in military time.  I have attempted numerous times to configure it to show Standard Time with AM and PM options.

Currently, I have written a partial to display the information.

*_form.html.haml*

```
= simple_form_for(@order, html: {class: 'form-horizontal'}) do |f|
    =f.input :date, label: "Date", input_html: {class:   DateTime.now.strftime("%B %C, %Y - %r")}
    =f.input :name, label: "Name", input_html: {class: "form-control"}
    =f.input :pickup, label: "Pick-up", input_html: {class: "form-control"}
    =f.input :pickuptime, label: "Pick-up Time", input_html: {class: "form- control"}
    %br/
    =f.button :submit, class: "btn btn-danger btn-lg"
```

Despite this, it still shows the form with a military time option.

How can I change the form so there is an option to select Standard Time with AM or PM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to validate your datetime object in your model, how you want that it actually looks like

and rails will view it the correct way for you.

usually u do that by i18n. But for you something like :

```
 class MyClass
    validate :myDatetime

    private
    def myDatetime
      date.strftime(%m.%d.%Y %H:%M)
    end
 end
```

should work.

A little hint, you don't have to specify in every form the class name of your simple form buttons.
You could just specify it in your config/initializers/simple_form.rb :

```
 config.button_class ='your btn name'
```

=> very DRY

Comment: I'm not sure why I still get an error: SyntaxError in OrdersController#index where it sites "date.strftime(%m.%d.%Y %H:%M)" as an unknown type of string in my Order model.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help you: https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/issues/1328
It seems you must build it by yourself.
Or if you are using bootstrap: http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/ (I never used it)